# how to access display of a pre-owned server?

Tags: command-line, remote-control, dell-poweredge

hey guys i purchased this server at an auction and i'm using it for my own home server for web development. It came without a cable for the back so i bought one off amazon (VGA CABLE) It's a server from 2007, the Dell Poweredge 2950 and it's still got some power in it. Depending on how these next few weeks go i'll install a remote access card in the back (far left, first picture is where the port goes). that keyhole is locked, inside is accessible.[two picutres, front and back of the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2FbE.jpg)

Now when i hooked it up to my monitor with the VGA cable the screen was fully black  but it looks like it's on but black screen. i googled around and someone wrote that if the screen is black it could be access with with pressing the ESC key, that hasn't worked. my screen when on VGA https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CkW2.jpg

Is there a way to format this servers without display, what options do i have accessing this>? Command line access?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I read this and agree that's what i've done, giving access of where it has come from (what limitations of information i have and the pictures/what i've tried with it.) the problem i have is getting the display to show anythign with it plugged in. I want to access the internal files. what am i missing here?

Comment: The original revision of your question didn't include a screenshot.